# Uniform convergence method?

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am self-studying analysis and have reached the topic of uniform convergence. When it comes to series, it seems that Weierstrass' M-test is a powerful tool to determine uniform convergence. However, do similar tests exist in the case of sequences?

In my book (not by anybody famous), there is a single example in which uniform convergence is shown: as per the definition, we wish to show that $d(f_n,f) \rightarrow 0$. Coincidentally, this turned out to be the supremum of a neat function defined on a closed, bounded interval: so calculate the point of maxima, insert it, and see if it goes to zero. Fairly straight-forward.

**What else can one do?** Are all problems at my level (first course analysis, early undergrad) expected to be solved in this way?. What other techniques are common? When do they work, when don't they?

Here's one I picked from the exercises: $$f_n(x) = \frac{\ln x^n }{1 + x^n}, \ \ x \in [\alpha,\infty), \ \alpha > 1$$

Answer (score 4):

For a sequence $\{f_n\}$ that converges pointless to a function $f$, the usual way to prove uniform convergence is to find a number sequence $M_n$ such that
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le M_n\quad\forall x,\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=0.
$$
Sometimes this can be achieved using calculus t0 find the maximum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$.

In your example it is easy to see that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. If $x\ge\alpha>1$ and $n\ge2$ then
$$
0<f_n(x)=\frac{n\log x}{1+x^n}\le n\,\frac{\log x}{x}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}\le\frac{n}{\alpha^{n-1}}.
$$
Since $\alpha>1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n/\alpha^{n-1}=0$ and the convergence is uniform.

To disprove uniform convergence, a useful technique is to find $x_n$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\ge\delta$ or all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

For a series of positive functions, the Weierstrass M-test is the only test you can use.

For a series where the sign of the function value changes with change in the argument, you can use Abel's test or Dirichlet test.

Comment: "the only test...": It's not clear to me whether you mean to be saying the following is false, but for the record it's true: There exists a sequence of continuous functions $f_n\ge0$ defined on $[0,1]$ such that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly, but the M-test does not apply; if $M_n$ is any sequence of constants with $|f_n|\le M_n$ then $\sum M_n=\infty$.

Comment: I am not sure I get your point. My apologies. Why will the M-test not apply to positive functions?

Comment: It's a fact that there exist $f_n\ge0$ such that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly, although this cannot be shown by the M-test. My point: when you say "the only test you can use is the M-test" it seems possible you think otherwise, or that someone is in any case going to read you as saying otherwise. I'll try to fit the example into a comment...

Comment: For $n>=0$ and $0\le j<2^n$ define $I_{n,j} = [j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}]$. Let $f_n$ be a continuous function with $0\le f_n\le 1$, which vanishes outside $I_{n,j}$, and which takes the value $1$ at some point. Let $(g_k)$ be the obvious enumeration of $2^{-n}f_{n,j}$:
$g_0,g_1,g_3\dots=f_{0,0}, 1/2f_{1,0},1/2f_{1,1},1/4f_{2,0},\dots$.
Then $\sum g_n$ converges uniformly, but this does not follow from the M-test: $\sum_n\sup g_n=\infty$.

Comment: Oh my apologies again. I was actually talking about approaching a problem from a "practical" point of view. In fact, I have never really faced a situation where the M-test went wrong.

Comment: Of course what you said is perfectly appropriate in the context of an answer to a calculus student, didn't mean to suggest otherwise. But the phenomenon does come up. For example the class of uniformly convergent Fourier series is strictly larger than the class of absolutely convergence Fourier series.